# Obtaining and counting overlapping line segments after adding ST_ClosestPoints with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, overlapping-features, splitting, snapping

I have some LineStrings that overlap in some segments, but not necessarily with coinciding vertices, like shown in the example below. With PostGIS I would like to extract all "segments" and count how many LineStrings are overlapping here (1 would mean that nothing overlaps).

As an example, consider the following situation: Two LineStrings (`LINESTRING(0 0, 100 40)` and `LINESTRING(50 20, 150 60)`) and a point `P` (`POINT(75 25)`).

Easy to see, that the LineStrings overlap between `B(50,20)` and `C(100,40)` as shown here:

[image]

My approach is:

- Extract all (distinct, in the case of duplicate vertices) vertices (`A,B,C,D` in a first step, see below) from the LineStrings and make a MULTIPOINT of it
- `ST_Split` the LineStrings and count the geometries

I achieve this with the following query (sample data included):

```
with
    sample(geom, id) as (values
        (st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(0, 0), st_makepoint(100, 40)]), 1),
        (st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(50, 20), st_makepoint(150, 60)]), 2)),

    splitter(geom) as (select st_union(distinct x.geom) as splitter from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).*  from sample) as x)

select count(y.geom), st_asText(y.geom) as segment from (select (st_dump(st_split(s.geom, splitter.geom))).* from splitter, sample as s) as y group by y.geom
```

returning the expected result (2 occurences of `B-C`):

```
count | segment
----------------------------
1     | LINESTRING(0 0,50 20)
2     | LINESTRING(50 20,100 40)
1     | LINESTRING(100 40,150 60)
```

**To make things a little more interesting**, I add a point `P'` to LineString `B-D` (cp. above, LINESTRING(50 20, 150 60)), which is the *closest point* on `B-D` to `P`.

Running the same query again (with the modifications to the sample data mentioned above)...

```
with 
    sample(geom, id) as (values
        (st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(0, 0), st_makepoint(100, 40)]), 1),
        (st_addpoint(st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(50, 20), st_makepoint(150, 60)]),
                     st_closestpoint(st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(50, 20), st_makepoint(150, 60)]), st_makepoint(75, 15)),1), 2)),

    splitter(geom) as (select st_union(distinct x.geom) as geom from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).*  from sample) as x)

select count(y.geom), st_astext(y.geom) as segment from (select (st_dump(st_split(s.geom, splitter.geom))).* from splitter, sample as s) as y group by y.geom
```

... I expect (not knowing the exact coordinates of `P`) six segments, with two of them twice:

```
count | segment
----------------------------
1     | LINESTRING(0 0,50 20)
2     | LINESTRING(50 20, P'x P'y)
2     | LINESTRING(P'x P'y, 100 40)
1     | LINESTRING(100 40,150 60)
```

... but I get

```
count | segment
-------------------------------
1     | LINESTRING(0 0,50 20)
1     | LINESTRING(50 20,69.8275862068966 27.9310344827586)
1     | LINESTRING(50 20,100 40)
1     | LINESTRING(69.8275862068966 27.9310344827586,150 60)
```

So apparently, `C` does not split `B-P'-D` (but `P'` does) and `P'` does not split `A-C` (but `B` does).

Selection of the vertices works fine:

```
-- create sample data
select distinct st_astext(x.geom) as vertices from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).*  from sample) as x

vertices
-------------------------
POINT(0 0)
POINT(100 40)
POINT(150 60)
POINT(50 20)
POINT(69.8275862068966 27.9310344827586)
```

So `ST_Split` works only when points lie *exactly* on the LineStrings, but I would expect that `P'` matches this condition for both LineStrings (or none).

Does adding `P'` modify the geometry in a way that `ST_Split` does not work as expected or what might I am doing wrong here? Or is the whole approach likely to be unsuitable? Or is `ST_ClosestPoint` unsuitable to create `P'`?

Comment: do you get different results if you guarantee both lines are equal by e.g. snapping them to a grid? after all, P' is created on/for one line only and 13 decimal digits leave *a lot* of room for inequality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your frustration with cutting lines with points is not unmarked. Check out this [feature request](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2192) from 2013 asking to *add tolerance parameter to ST_Split for splitting lines by points*.

The solution is to **snap the lines to the points**. Note that snapping the points to the lines does not work.

Your example with `ST_Snap()` added:

```
with
    sample(geom, id) as (values
        (st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(0, 0), st_makepoint(100, 40)]), 1),
        (st_addpoint(st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(50, 20), st_makepoint(150, 60)]),
                     st_closestpoint(st_makeline(array[st_makepoint(50, 20), st_makepoint(150, 60)]), st_makepoint(75, 15)),1), 2)),

    splitter(geom) as (select st_union(distinct x.geom) as geom from (select (st_dumppoints(geom)).*  from sample) as x)

select count(y.geom), st_astext(y.geom) as segment 
from (
    select (st_dump(st_split(ST_Snap(s.geom, splitter.geom, 0.00000001), splitter.geom))).* 
    from splitter, sample as s
) as y group by y.geom
```

Output:

```
count | segment
-------------------------------
1     | LINESTRING(0 0,50 20)
2     | LINESTRING(50 20,69.8275862068966 27.9310344827586)
2     | LINESTRING(69.8275862068966 27.9310344827586,100 40)
1     | LINESTRING(100 40,150 60)
```

Comment: great stuff, snapperific!